# start up sculpting a human head

Tags: sculpting

I'd like to start Blender by sculpting a human head . How can I import a ready made model head , and where can I find the classical sculpting tools of sculpting?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer** - you can import your head by going to *File > Import > Wavefront (.obj)*. If your model isn't a .obj file, select the other option that matches yours. Sculpting tools are in the sculpt panel, top of the screen under *Sculpting*.

**Advice** - do not start with a head. If you're new to Blender, start with something simple. Human head is a really complicated model even good artists can struggle with. :-)